# ForkJoinPool executes task two times

Tags: java, executorservice, java-threads, forkjoinpool

The following code prints out 'Inside...' two times.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(3);

    forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
      System.out.println("Inside...");
    }).invoke();
  }
}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call both `submit` and `invoke`. `ForkJoinPool#submit` publishes the task to the pool, and will also execute it once a thread is ready.

The method also returns `ForkJoinTask`, on which you call `invoke`, performing the task again and waiting for its result.

Comment: But it is strange that the behavior I describe happens occasionally. So if I run the code multiple times it has different behavior. Sometimes it prints single line and sometimes it prints two lines.

Comment: `invoke` is called straight away and always prints "Inside" but `submit` is scheduled for execution and may or may not have enough time to run before the program exits depending on thread scheduling which is not deterministic.